# How to change state of child component in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a parent component like this:

```
     class Parent extends Component {

      onChangeState=()=>{ 
         //I want to change it here
       }

        render(){

    return(
          <child  />)
         })
}
```

*I want to change child component's state in parent. How can I do that ?*

```
class Child extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      item: ''
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: If parent's state is changing it will re-render, you can send new props to child.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to define the state in the parent and pass it as a prop to the child. Then, your parent has full control over the state and a state change will cause a rerender of the child and its prop will be updated. This yields in the same effect.

```js
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { item: '' };
    }
    
    onChangeState = (newItem) => {
        this.setState({ item: newItem })
    }

    return (
       <Child state={this.state} />
    )
}
```

```js
class Child extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props)
      }

     render() {
        return (
           <Text>{this.props.state.item}</Text>
        )
     }
}
```